# Why does an Ada compiler let range violations pass? Why is my type declaration a runtime entity?

Tags: types, runtime, range, ada, compile-time

Why does Ada compiler let range violations pass?
It does give warning, but why does it let it pass if it is an error in any case? Is there a practical scenario in which this is a useful behaviour?

And most importantly: Why is type declaration a runtime entity?
I mean the 3rd line of the code example is something I expect to be evaluated ahead of time.
I thought that only the 5th line will "make it" into the executable. Why not? Is that something useful? Am I missing or misinterpreting something here?

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
procedure question is
    subtype Test is Natural range -1 .. 10;
begin
    Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("foobar");
end;
```

Note: Result is identical with "type Test is new Natural range -1..10;"

Note: GNAT 4.6

Comment: Worth mentioning which Ada compiler and version. Incidentally, did you know that Gnat is not, by default, an Ada compiler? It needs a certain set of compiler flags to turn on certain checks required by the standard!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This comp.lang.ada message](http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Ada/comp.lang.ada/2007-11/msg00087.html) suggests that you need at least `-gnato -fstack-check` command line options for Gnat to be a compliant Ada compiler.

However that's not the issue here : the compiler does warn about the range error; with Gnat I get:

```
gnatmake -gnato -fstack-check question
question.adb:3:35: warning: static value out of range of type "Standard.Natural"
question.adb:3:35: warning: "Constraint_Error" will be raised at run time
```

and the obvious error at run time.

In this case because the range is static the compiler could have caught the error; but as you are guessing, in general the type cannot be fully determined until runtime, as in the following example.

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Command_Line;

procedure question is
   subtype Arguments is Natural range 1 .. Ada.Command_Line.Argument_Count;
begin
   for i in Arguments loop
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Argument " & integer'image(i) & 
                            " is " & Ada.Command_Line.Argument(i)); 
      declare
         OneArg : constant String := Ada.Command_Line.Argument(i);
         subtype Characters is Natural range OneArg'range;
      begin
         null;  -- process the string here
      end;   
   end loop;
end;
```

Here neither subtype is known until you run the program.

The declare block shows a related pattern I find very useful, that allows not just variable [sub]types, but allocates variable sized objects on the stack so that they are automatically reclaimed and re-sized on each loop iteration. (You could allocate with "new" and free with "unchecked_deallocation" as in other languages but very often, as here, there is simply no need)