# Why is Ada not raising a constraint error?

Tags: constraints, ada

I have the following declaration of an anonymous subtype:

```
testConstraint : Integer Range -5 .. 5;
```

Then later, when assigning it:

```
testConstraint := -6;
```

Why am I not getting a `Constraint_Error`?

Additional Details:

- There are no `pragma suppress` statements in the code file in question (though there are some in files added via `with`;
- The build is done via `gprbuild` using GPS 5.0.2 and GNAT Pro 6.4.2
- There are the following flags used: `-gnatf -gnatp -gnat2012 -d`
- It's also got flags coming in from "external" in the .gpr file - but I don't know where these are or what this means.

Comment: what compiler and compile flags are you using? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526945/why-does-an-ada-compiler-let-range-violations-pass-why-is-my-type-declaration-a/14527545#14527545

Comment: That's interesting- would the same be applicable for gprbuild?

Comment: I did try adding the arguments but it did not have any effect.

Comment: I got compiler warning after removing -gnatp switch, but I had to run clean & build, it was not enough to run just build after removing -gnatp switch. I used GNAT GPS 2017

Comment: OK, so looks like -gnatp disables runtime checks, including range checks, but -gnat-p removes this switch if it's been added (via an import). I am debating whether to delete this question, since it was asked out of utter ignorance - but can leave it here if people think it would be useful to future askers?

Comment: @theMayer The question is real enough (even if you could read the answer in the manual), so I've added an answer for completeness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Timur and @theMayer notes:

> `-gnatp` suppresses all checks.

From the documentation:

> **-gnatp**
>
> This switch causes the unit to be compiled as though pragma Suppress (All_checks) had been present in the source. Validity checks
>   are also eliminated (in other words -gnatp also implies -gnatVn). Use
>   this switch to improve the performance of the code at the expense of
>   safety in the presence of invalid data or program bugs.

Suppressing all checks is a really bad idea.  You can do it for specific units, if you have proven that the checks aren't required (for example by using SPARK), **and** you have measured that suppressing all checks gives you a performance improvement which you need.

The solution is to use add the compiler flag `-gnat-p` (and then - if the requirements are met - suppressing checks for individual files).