# creating a subtype of Positive where range is not known until runtime

Tags: ada

I am trying to create a graph package for a fixed sized complete graph but the size will not be known until runtime.  I want to represent a vertex as a positive in the range 1..num_vertices.  I have tried to create a generic graph package with the number of vertices as a generic parameter.  This package will have to be instantiated in my code which creates visibility/scope problems for the graph package.  Any suggestion?  Thank you.

More Detail: Graphs is generic package

num_vertices := 4;
declare
package My_Graphs is new Graphs(num_vertices);
g: My_Graphs.Graph;
begin
...

I need to used My_Graphs in another package that contains graph algorithms.

Comment: When you know the size, start a Declare block. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526945/why-does-an-ada-compiler-let-range-violations-pass-why-is-my-type-declaration-a/14527545#14527545

Answer (score 4):

Subtype constraints do not have to be static, so you can do things like

```
Max_Vertices : constant Positive := Some_Input_Function;

subtype Vertex_Number is Positive range 1 .. Max_Vertices;
```

Comment: Just to add to this, you can have a value as the parameter of the generic, and then instantiate the generic with the result of the input function.